# Навсегда свернуть #region или часть кода

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Часто бывает так, что когда в коде создаешь пару из `#region` `#endregion` то после перезапуска VS, или даже просто запуска приложения для отладки (и по другим мистическим причинам) весь код, свернутый с помощью этих регионов опять разворачивается.

Собственно вопрос - как свернуть их навсегда?

P.S. Подойдет любой метод для сворачивания законченных участков кода

Comment: Вообще, эти настройки хранятся в .suo файле и не должны сами сбрасываться. Можете попробовать [советы](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19178062/5752652) для 2010 студии, но сам не проверял - я хейтер регионов.

Comment: Использовать partial-классы и все что не хотите видеть выносить в отдельный файл

Comment: Это [Turning off automatic outlining in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709212/turning-off-automatic-outlining-in-visual-studio) ?

Comment: Нет, имеется ввиду что можно дописать к классу слово partial (`public partial class Abc {}`)и располагать один класс в нескольких файлах. По мне паршиал использовать в такой ситуации не стоит.

Comment: Горячие клавиши: `Ctrl + M + M` - сворачивает-разворачивает текущий блок кода. `Ctrl + M + L` - сворачивает-разворачивает весь код.

Comment: @vitidev Возможно, проблема в том, что я не могу найти этот параметр. Может быть я слепой? Если не трудно - подскажите его название по русски, ибо, может быть его в VS2019 вообще выпилили?

Comment: Он там есть в нескольких местах. И по тому пути, что по ссылке, тоже есть. Откройте tool -> options и там слева будет строка поиска. Вбейте туда "outlining" и он отфильтрует все разделы где это есть